# Android: How to create negative values in plots axis based on achartengine lib?

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to create XY plot with positive and negative numbers on both axys. By default achartnegine shows negative values of series but the start popint is always zero^ graph start from zero and next nubmer is something like -50, -40 etc. I have tried to avoid this but haven;t succed yet. Could you please suggest the right approach?

```
                XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries(seriesXY);

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            //renderer.setXAxisMin(-10f);
            //renderer.setYAxisMin(-250f);
            //renderer.setBarSpacing(SPACING);
            //renderer.setRange(new double[] { -250d, 250d});
            XYSeriesRenderer sRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            sRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            sRenderer.setFillBelowLine(false);
            sRenderer.setChartValuesSpacing(SPACING);
            sRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.WHITE);
            sRenderer.setFillPoints(false);

            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(sRenderer);
            renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
            renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
            renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
            renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLUE);
            renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
            renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);

        GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
                getActivity(),
                dataset, renderer);
        plot.removeAllViews();
        plot.addView(chartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));

        chartView.repaint();
```

I use LineChartView

Comment: Please post a full example with data, such as I understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Excuse me, I can't post the code to show my problem. I hust write a simple example what I did in real project to clarify my question. My question is how to show negative values on both axys?

Comment: Well, if you provide an example showing how you add data to your dataset, I may be able to spot the problem you have. AChartEngine does support negative values on both axis if used correctly. I don't need to see your entire code, just an example showing the problem. The code you posted above just creates a series and a renderer and sets some properties on the renderer. I am sure the problem is related to the way you populate your data.

Comment: I have edited a part with my code. Could you please provide the solution is suited for my aim?

Comment: I still see no code that adds data to your seriesXY. What do you mean by "the start popint is always zero^ graph start from zero and next nubmer is something like -50, -40"?

Comment: This data as this [-5, -4, -10, 0 , 78, 87, -29]. I mean that I want to show negative number of my SYseries as classsic grapg where zero in center of axys and negative numbers from left of it, positive numbers right of it; for Y it is the same. But now I see zero in the left corner and negative numbers in top and right sides of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot put the axis in the center of the chart with AChartEngine as it is out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do it with other types of charts or this lib hasn't this feature?